# How to flatten a numpy array based on frequency to get the correct standard deviation?

Tags: python, numpy, standard-deviation

I can very easily get the standard deviation of some numbers in a 1D list in numpy like below:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 500])
sd = np.std(arr1)
print(sd)
```

But my data is in the form of a 2D list, in which the second value of each inner list, is the frequency:

```
arr2 = np.array([[100, 3], [200, 2], [500, 1]])
```

How can I flatten it based on frequency (change `arr2` into `arr1`), to get the correct standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arr2[:, 0].repeat(arr2[:, 1])`.

Answer (score 1):

While @timgeb's (good) answer is the most straightforward, this might not be efficient if you have very large inputs such as `np.array([[100, 3000], [200, 20000], [500, 100]])`

In this case you can compute the standard deviation manually

```
v,r = arr2.T
n = r.sum()
avg = (v*r).sum()/n
std = np.sqrt((r*(v-avg)**2).sum()/n)
```

output: `141.4213562373095`

Or use [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.html):

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW

v,r = arr2.T
DescrStatsW(v, weights=r, ddof=0).std
# 141.4213562373095
```

Comment: Your answer is actually better. Its more efficient and preserves the original array. But since I literally said "flatten a numpy array based on frequency" in my question, I think it might be unfair to timgeb, if I mark your answer as correct instead of his. I hope you understand.

Comment: @Muhammad sure, my goal wasn't to "get the mark", just to improve the Q/A with an alternative ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole array flattened, you can use `ravel()`

```
arr2.ravel()
# output: array([100,   3, 200,   2, 500,   1])
```

If you want a specific column, you can select all rows and use the index of the column

```
arr2[:,1]
# output: array([3, 2, 1])
arr2[:,0]
# output: array([100, 200, 500])
```

To get the standard deviation, you can add `.std()` at the end

```
sd = arr2.ravel().std()
# or
sd = arr2[:,0].std()
# or 
sd = arr2[:,1].std()
# etc
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the question. But thanks for the effort